# How to display single Image from a string containing list of image url separated by comma in React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am calling API which is returning array of objects and in each object there are 3 or 4 images URL are there which are separated by comma i want to display single image how I can achieve it ?

My string format is like this

```
"images":  "https://ins3.amazonaws.com/event_pics/event_image_849287938.png,  
           https://ins3.amazonaws.com/event_pics/event_image_849287938.png,  
           https://ins3.amazonaws.com/event_pics/event_image_849287938.png,  
           https://ins3.amazonaws.com/event_pics/event_image_849287938.png"
```

I am using this to display data

```js
           {
               item.images.split(",").map((img, index) => 
                   index == 1 ?  <Image source={{uri : img}}  style={styles.image} />: null
              )
           }
```

I am displaying my data using flatlist

Any suggestions or idea how to do it ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you should separate each string and save them in an array. The best way for this is the `split` method.

```
var images = 'https://ins3.amazonaws.com/event_pics/event_image_849287938.png,  
       https://ins3.amazonaws.com/event_pics/event_image_849287938.png,  
       https://ins3.amazonaws.com/event_pics/event_image_849287938.png,  
       https://ins3.amazonaws.com/event_pics/event_image_849287938.png';
var imagesArr = images.split(',');
```

After having the array of images, it'd be much easier to show the first, second, or third ones, according to the index of the array.

Comment: Thanks @aliSasani  this i know but how to do it in react native I want to know do you have any idea

Comment: for testing purpose i used this <Text> {item.images.split(',').map((step)=> <Text>{step}{"\n"}</Text>)}</Text> it is showing images URL  but how to display single image ? @aliSasani

Comment: Do you have problems in showing the single image or all images in the slider?

Comment: I want to show single image first then in next page I want to show all images in slider @aliSasani

Comment: I can't get your main purpose. But, I'll try to describe it step by step. First, you need to fetch the data in the componentdidmount and store it in the state. Then, show the first element of the array that I wrote, in the first screen.

Comment: Then, pass the array to the component that is responsible for showing the slider. You can use a suitable UI library or package to create a slider of images.

Comment: i am getting list of  objects from API  call I am displaying some information of each object In  card and when someone click on it then i am displaying full details

Comment: in first screen i am not using slider because only one image i want to display but in another screen i want to display all images so i am using slider there

Comment: Sorry, I can't get which part is your problem.

Comment: Load the data and store it in an array -->  Show the first element on the first page --> show the rest of them as a slider in the other pages

Comment: okay leave about the second screen just help me to display single image @aliSasani

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228056/discussion-between-haryanvideveloper-and-ali-sasani).

Answer (score 0):

Use the split method to split every single value then take out the value that you need for example:

```
const images  = 'image1, image2, image3'

const result  = images.split(',')[1]

console.log(result) //image2
```

Comment: Thanks @Iftekhstudio i am using same but image is not displaying